# how to remove html select file options with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my project, I have 2 html select. I want to change the second select when the first select changed. But there is an issue. When I changed the first select, the second select writing over previous option values. I want to remove the previous option value when I changed the first select. I wrote this code:

```
 <script>
function docType() {
    var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?fl=DocType&group.field=DocType&group=true&q=PackName:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="&rows=10&sort=DocType%20asc&start=0&wt=json";
    var string="\"" + $("#PackName option:selected").val() + "\"";
var URL = URL_PREFIX+string+URL_MIDDLE;
$.ajax({
   url : URL,
   dataType : 'json',
   type:'get',
   json : 'json.wrf',
   success : function(data) {
      var docs = JSON.stringify(data.grouped.DocType.groups);
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
      for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
            $("#DocType").append($("<option>"+jsonData[i].groupValue+"</option>"));
       }
   },
 })
};
</script>
```

[this is first time changed first select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LcEA.png)

[this is second time changed first select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb9du.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `success` function, do the following:

```
$("#DocType").empty();
for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
   $("#DocType").append($("<option>"+jsonData[i].groupValue+"</option>"));
}
```

What this essentially does is removes the existing option tags and then re-populates them with the new values.

So this happens each time the first select value changes.